# Why doesn't ƒ show in my HTML for mobile browser?

Tags: html, char

I'm trying to get `ƒ` to show on all browsers…
But it only works on desktop

I put `<meta charset="UTF-8">` at the top… but will not show on mobile… it will only show `Æ’`

Why is this?
How do I get it to show properly?

Comment: It's possible that you have not got Byte Order Mark encoding on the file. Try opening up the HTML file in Notepad++ and changing the encoding from `UTF-8 without BOM` to `UTF-8`.

Comment: I'm on MacBook.

Comment: @ObsidianAge: A BOM at the start of an UTF-8 file is an abomination to be exterminated wherever encountered.

Comment: If all else fails try `&fnof;`